# Using curl with success while running containers

Tags: curl, docker, dockerfile, marklogic

I'm trying to build and run a Marklogic instance with Docker. Marklogic offer some nice http api, so, as final `CMD` in Dockerfile, I run two scripts who do some http requests by `curl` to properly configure Marklogic's instance as container starts up. But when I run my image,

```
docker run -p 7997-8002:7997-8002 --name gi-ml-container -e USER=admin -e PASSWORD=admin -e REALM=public -e HOST=gi-ml-container gi-marklogic
```

I got this error:

```
0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: gi-ml-container; Name or service not known
```

I thought conainer's name should be enought. How can I do `curl` to the container I am running by Dockerfile? Is this the right way?
I am using Docker 1.12.6, build 78d1802 on Ubuntu 16.04. Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM centos:centos7
ARG USER=admin
ARG PASSWORD=admin
ARG REALM=public
ARG HOST=localhost
RUN yum -y install glibc.i686 gdb.x86_64 redhat-lsb.x86_64 && yum clean all
RUN yum -y install initscripts && yum clean all
ENV PATH /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/opt/MarkLogic/mlcmd/bin
COPY MarkLogic-RHEL7-8.0-6.3.x86_64.rpm /tmp/MarkLogic-RHEL7-8.0-6.3.x86_64.rpm
COPY marklogic.admin.setup.sh /tmp/marklogic.admin.setup.sh
COPY marklogic.init.database.sh /tmp/marklogic.init.database.sh
RUN chmod +x /tmp/*.sh
RUN yum -y install /tmp/MarkLogic-RHEL7-8.0-6.3.x86_64.rpm
RUN rm /tmp/MarkLogic-RHEL7-8.0-6.3.x86_64.rpm
EXPOSE 7997 7998 7999 8000 8001 8002
CMD /etc/init.d/MarkLogic start && ./tmp/marklogic.init.database.sh -h $HOST && ./tmp/marklogic.admin.setup.sh -u $USER -p $PASSWORD -r $REALM -h $HOST && tail -f /dev/null
```

This Dockerfile uses two `.sh` files to configure the Marklogic instance as container starts. This is `marklogic.init.database.sh`:

```
TIMESTAMP=`curl -d "" -X POST http://${HOST}:8001/admin/v1/init`
```

and this is my `marklogic.admin.setup.sh`:

```
TIMESTAMP=`$CURL -X POST -H
"Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
--data "admin-username=${USER}" --data "admin-password=${PASS}" \
--data "realm=${SEC_REALM}" \
http://${HOST}:8001/admin/v1/instance-admin`
```

I pretty follow up what Maklogic shows in a couple of nice articles about how to do this [here](https://developer.marklogic.com/blog/building-a-marklogic-docker-container) and [here](https://developer.marklogic.com/blog/docker-marklogic-initialization).

Comment: You're running the curl on the same container, where Maklogic is running? So you can curl the own machine by calling localhost: ```TIMESTAMP=`curl -d "" -X POST http://localhost:8001/admin/v1/init` ```. This might help.

Comment: Hello! That was my first try but I got the same result: `Failed connect to localhost:8001; Connection refused`.

Comment: I am not quite sure when your curls are executed (I don't know Maklogic either). Typically, you assume that your container starts and then do an external curl to your container whether it is set up or not. This is what I'd suggest and what I'd put into my CI / testing workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things:

1) You have to specify the hostname with `-h` option in `docker run`: `-h gi-ml-container-d`

```
docker run -p 7997-8002:7997-8002 --name gi-ml-container -e USER=admin -e PASSWORD=admin -e REALM=public -e HOST=gi-ml-container-d -h gi-ml-container-d gi-marklogic
```

So you could change your Dockerfile and scripts without using `$HOST`, but they works just adding `-h` to the `docker run`.

2) When you start `MarkLogic` as a service, it gives back the control too quickly, so it is not yet running when the next command runs. So add a sleep to delay it:

```
CMD /etc/init.d/MarkLogic start && sleep 5 && /tmp/marklogic.init.database.sh -h $HOST && sleep 5 && /tmp/marklogic.admin.setup.sh -u $USER -p $PASSWORD -r $REALM -h $HOST && tail -f /dev/null
```

3) In `marklogic.admin.setup.sh` script be sure that `$CURL` is not empty. May be you can directly write `curl` in it. Also (may be is already correct and it is just a copy&paste problem) be sure `"Content type..."` is on the same line than `-X POST -H` (or concatenate it with `\` as you did in the following lines)

```
TIMESTAMP=`curl -X POST -H "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
--data "admin-username=${USER}" --data "admin-password=${PASS}" \
--data "realm=${SEC_REALM}" \
http://${HOST}:8001/admin/v1/instance-admin`
```

4) Finally, altough it should not have any impact, because you use an absolute path name for scripts in `/tmp`, you don't need to put `.` before them (so not `./tmp/marklogic.init.database.sh` but `/tmp/marklogic.init.database.sh` is enough and it is notdependet by your working directory.